# Magento 2 - REST API filter order data from shipping and billing address name and telephone number

Tags: magento2, rest-api, filter, search-criteria

I need to filter order data based on shipping and billing address name and telephone through rest api

For example In order to filter data through status my request url would be something like this:

```
https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]="processing"&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

let say this is my json decoded response from api, I only take the relevant part of response.

```
[billing_address] => Array
      (
                   [address_type] => billing
                   [city] => Karachi
                   [country_id] => PK
                   [customer_address_id] => 20
                   [email] => test@gmail.com
                   [entity_id] => 718
                   [firstname] => Test
                   [lastname] => User
                   [parent_id] => 360
                   [postcode] => 
                   [region] => Azad Kashmir
                   [region_code] => JK
                   [region_id] => 569
                   [street] => Array
                          (
                            [0] => Dha phase 5 , near anees Hussain phase 6
                          )

                   [telephone] => `1234567890
    )
```

Now I need to firstname, lastname and telephone in search criteria filter. So What would be my request url in order to filter data shipping and billing address name and telephone number

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Comment: I think for that GraphQL is better option than REST api.

Comment: Yes may be you are right but I eagerly need a solution through rest api and I am sure there should be a solution for this